# Having issue with mesh when in smooth mode

Tags: rendering, mesh

My issue is rather strange and not sure on a fix for it but when im in shade smooth mode the legs on my character are shaded a bit differently as i will show with an image if you guys have any ideas please let let me know if possible[image]

Comment: is the edge a crease edge or sharp? In edit mode select the edge loop and try right click to clear sharp, and if that doesn't do anything hit `n` and in the item tab make sure the mean crease is set to 0

Comment: Flipped normals? Vertices not connected? You can always upload your file to [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), if you want to take us a look at it and place the link in your question. Please use the edit link below your question, if you want to add more info.

Answer (score 1):

The shading is broken along an edge-loop, in those cases i would always check the normals first.

**Solution:**

1. Go in edit mode <kbd>Tab</kbd>
2. Select all with <kbd>A</kbd>
3. Follow up with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> **Recalculate Outside** to correct the normals.

**Explanation:**
You can always check the normals with a "*color indicating overlay*" by switching on **Face Orientation**.
[image]

Example:
[image]
*left looks similar to your shading, right shows the overlay activated*

The Entire model should be blue if all normals are ok, if red is visible outside then those areas have bad (facing inwards) normals and you can either manually select the red faces and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to open the **Normals** menu
[image]
and **Flip** the normals of the selected faces, or use the *in most cases easier*, "select all and recalculate outside" method explained at the beginning. There are cases where the **Recalculate Outside** function does not manage to fix all, just mentioning. In those cases manual flipping would be needed.

Happy Blending.

Comment: Thank you soo much for your quick response and i think i fixed it thanks to your help